# Is a test environment of the Artifactory Server of a productive system free of charge

Tags: artifactory

We are interested in the Pro version of JFrog Artifactory.
This costs about $ 3000.
We have a test environment from all our systems and would also like to have this for the Artifactory Server.
Is a test installation (backup of the original) also paid for?

Georg

Answer (score 6):

JFrog Artifactory business model is a license per instance. This means that every live instance of Artifactory needs to have a different license. That includes test instances and QA instances.

Hope this helps clarify the issue

Comment: Oh, that will be expensive!

Comment: Can't help you with that mate, I'm a tech guy... just answering a question you asked. :)